# What is the fastest way to iterate over a Unicode string and replace characters in Cython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, cython, text-processing

I want to iterate over gigabytes of text and replace some characters. It is a very heavy text normalizer with hunderds of replacement candidates.

With python, it would take days to do the task of reading the file line by line and character by character and do the replacements using a dictionary. I am therefore looking forward to Cython to speed up the task for me, as with C++ I get 60+ times speed boost.

So, I have a huge amount of **Unicode** strings:

```
strings = ['AAAABBACCDDDD', 'ACCBDBCCCCDA', 'ABCAD', 'ABCCCCCCCC']
```

and I want to itreate over them character by character and perform some repalcements:

```
A -> G
C -> G
D -> B
```

The mapping list is of length 1000+. Please also bear in mind that the strings are in Unicode and contain hundreds of unique non-standard characters from different languages.

Comment: Can you clarify what your actual question is? If you already have a working, fast C++ version, why don't you use that? What have you tried to do it in Cython?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I actually want to implement it in Cython simply to learn Cython, as I want to do many more text manipulations that are not easily implementable in C++. Please also let me know if there is a better way than Cython.

Comment: The problem with unicode in Python is that it is immutable, you still can modify them in-place - but you must really know what you are doing, otherwise strange things can happen. And if you only have ASCII-characters maybe having them in a bytearray rather then unicode would make things easier (probably c++ doesn't represent the data as unicode as well).

Comment: @ead The strings being immutable in python won't be a problem in this particular task, as I can populate a new empty string with the new sequence of characters. The main problem is the iteratation itself, which takes much more time in python than C++.

Comment: In your Python code, do you actually iterate through the string? Are you aware of [``str.translate``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and similar?